# Проблема с использованием System.Text.Json вместе с генератором исходного кода

Tags: c#, code-generator

Хотел из `json` файла нагенерировать C#-классов с помощью современного `ISourceGenerator`. Данные - массив блоков Minecraft.

Всё бы ничего, но использование `JsonSerizlizer.Deserialize` постоянно вызывает следующую ошибку, в следствии которой мой генератор крашится:

```
Генератору "BlocksGenerator" не удалось создать источник. Это не повлияет на выходные данные и ошибки компиляции, которые могут возникнуть в результате. Тип возникшего исключения: "FileNotFoundException", сообщение: "Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл."
```

У меня есть простейшее решение, структура такая:

```
- Minever.Data
- Minever.Data.Core
|-- IBlock.cs
- Minever.Data.Generators
|-- BlocksGenerators.Block.cs
|-- BlocksGenerators.cs
```

GitHub проекта: https://github.com/iiKuzmychov/Minever.Data.

BlocksGenerators.Block.cs:

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace Minever.Data.Generators;

public partial class BlocksGenerator
{
    internal class Block
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
    }
}
```

BlocksGenerator.cs:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text;
using Minever.Data.Core;
using Minever.Data.Generators.Utils;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace Minever.Data.Generators;

[Generator]
public partial class BlocksGenerator : ISourceGenerator
{
    public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
    {
        var json   = @"[ {""id"":0, ""name"": ""air""} ]"; // json для теста
        var blocks = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Block[]>(json)!; // в ЭТОЙ строке исключение

        var sourceBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        sourceBuilder.AppendLine($"using {nameof(Minever)}.{nameof(Data)}.{nameof(Core)};");
        sourceBuilder.AppendLine();
        sourceBuilder.AppendLine($"namespace {nameof(Minever)}.{nameof(Data)}.Blocks;");
        sourceBuilder.AppendLine();

        foreach (var block in blocks)
        {
            sourceBuilder.AppendLine(GenerateBlockSourceCode(block));
            sourceBuilder.AppendLine();
        }

        context.AddSource("Blocks.g.cs", SourceText.From(sourceBuilder.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8));
    }

    public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
    {
#if DEBUG
        if (!Debugger.IsAttached)
            Debugger.Launch();
#endif
    }

    private string GenerateBlockSourceCode(Block block) =>
        $@"public class {block.Name.ToPascalCase()} : {nameof(IBlock)}
{{
    public int {nameof(IBlock.Id)} {{ get; }} = {block.Id};
    public string {nameof(IBlock.Name)} {{ get; }} = {block.Name};
}}";
}
```

Minever.Data.Generators.sln:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>11.0</LangVersion>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
    <EnforceExtendedAnalyzerRules>true</EnforceExtendedAnalyzerRules>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="3.3.4">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" Version="4.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="7.0.1" GeneratePathProperty="true" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Minever.Data.Core\Minever.Data.Core.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <PropertyGroup>
    <GetTargetPathDependsOn>$(GetTargetPathDependsOn);GetDependencyTargetPaths</GetTargetPathDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="GetDependencyTargetPaths">
    <ItemGroup>
      <TargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker Include="$(PKGSystem_Text_Json)\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Text.Json.dll" IncludeRuntimeDependency="false" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  
</Project>
```

**UPD:**

Попробовал изменить платформу генератора на .NET 7. После этого он перестал запускаться, в принципе, и имеется следующая ошибка:

```
Экземпляр анализатора Minever.Data.Generators.BlocksGenerator невозможно создать из D:\IT Projects\Other\Minever.Data\src\Minever.Data.Generators\bin\Debug\net7.0\Minever.Data.Generators.dll : Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл."
```

Comment: А не пробовали взять `Newtonsoft.Json`? + Генерация выглядит страшноватой, не пробовали посмотреть в сторону t4?

Comment: Только что протестил на голом .NET 6 - все работает. У меня ощущение, что что-то не так с `.netstandard`. Хотя всё в теории должно работать.

Comment: @icYFTL Newtonsoft.Json устарел.

Comment: С какой целью используете Net Standard? Для .NET Core приложений не следует его использовать. .NET Standard нужен для совместимости с .NET Framework 4.x, а вам нужна такая совместимость? Если не нужна, делайте библиотеку под .NET 6. `System.Text.Json` частично несовместим с .NET Standard. В частности, не может загрузить несовместимую библиотеку, которая содержит интерфейс `IAsyncEnumerable` (о чем и говорит исключение). Возможно есть портированный System.Text.Json, подходящий под .NET Standard 2.0, но я не искал, поищите в NuGet пакетах...

Comment: @aepot, не согласен насчет Newtonsoft.Json. Он по-приятнее как по мне.

Comment: @aepot во всех туториалах майков по `ISourceGenerator` сказано что они поддерживаются пока только в `.netstandard2.0`

Comment: @iiKuzmychov потому что в .NET Core Roslyn надо использовать. Там тоже все это есть, только на других API базируется. Но если вам так очень сильно нужна совместимость с .NET Framework 4.x и другими старыми API, то поддержу совет про Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: @icYFTL дело не в приятности. Во-первых System.Text.Json очень сильно быстрее, если правильно с ним дружить. Во-вторых, автор у этих библиотек - один и тот же человек. А вся приятность заключается в навыках использования. Местами System.Text.Json [может больше](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-source-generator/), чем его предшественник.

Comment: @iiKuzmychov https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/ вот примеры на базе .NET 5, ни о каком .NET Standard там даже речи не идет.

Comment: @aepot, раньше читал - Newtonsoft вроде как мощнее был. Видимо, я не уследил за развитием `System.Text.Json`.

Comment: @icYFTL всё верно, он быстро развивается.

Comment: @aepot и насчет .netstandard 2.0. По идее - он же должен уметь нормально в System.Text.Json? Это же просто апи базовых классов. Все что умеет .netstandard должно быть также реализовано в топе (.NET/.NET Framework/.NET Core)?

Comment: @icYFTL родная либа может и не поддерживать Standard, он уже объявлен мертвым. Вероятно, как я выше писал, поможет скачивание более старой версии System.Text.Json из NuGet

Comment: @aepot, а т.е. уже нету этой прослойки между common infrastructure и .NET?

Comment: @icYFTL что-то еще есть, но постепенно разлагается. .NET Core 3.1 был основной переходной версией, и недавно у него закончился срок поддержки. Можно считать, что мосты в прошлое сожжены официально.

Comment: @aepot `вот примеры на базе .NET 5, ни о каком .NET Standard там даже речи не идет`. В вашем примере в генераторе используется netstandard2.0: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/#hello-world-source-generator-edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из того что я вижу и пишу в комментариях к вопросу, здесь 2 основных пути решения:

1. Мигрировать библиотеку на .NET Core 3/5/6/7 (.NET Core 3.1 может быть несовместим с `ISourceGenerator`, поэтому рекомендую .NET 6 и новее)
2. Использовать совместимый со старыми API JSON.NET (Newtonsoft.Json) вместо System.Text.Json

Все остальные варианты, такие как выкачивание более старых версий System.Text.Json из NuGet выглядят костыльными и не стоят вашего внимания, на мой взгляд (`Include="System.Text.Json" Version="7.0.1"` - взять версию постарше).

Выбор решения за вами и зависит от требований к проекту.

Comment: на счёт первого пути решения обновил вопрос

Comment: @iiKuzmychov NuGet пакеты лишние удалите. И у вас возможно не установлен .NET 7 SDK.

Comment: установлен точно, на второй день выхода установил

Comment: просто как я и говорил, и по вашей ссылке на туториал также, нужно использовать стандарт 2.0, можете перечитать `.csproj` https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/#hello-world-source-generator-edition

Comment: @iiKuzmychov тогда может взятие версии нугет пакета постарше поможет?

Comment: помог переход на ньтонсофт, но теперь меня студия удивляет тем, что файлы генерируются заново только после закрытия-открытия студии